# Click button to add a css style with js

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve is to click one button and then the .clicked class will be added to the button I am clicking. But I also want to remove the class when I click one of the other buttons.

```
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

Javascript

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    var parentElement = this.parentElement;

    if (this.classList.length <= 2) {
    this.classList.add("clicked");

  } else {
    this.classList.remove("clicked");

  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/saj9oxyv/7/

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use `querySelector` to grab the current "clicked" element, remove the class, and then add the class to the clicked element.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    var parentElement = this.parentElement;
    var previousElement = document.querySelector('.clicked');

    if (previousElement) {
        previousElement.classList.remove('clicked');
    }

    if (this.classList.length <= 2) {
    this.classList.add("clicked");

  } else {
    this.classList.remove("clicked");

  }
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "remember" which one was clicked:

```js
var lastBtn;
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  if (lastBtn)
    lastBtn.classList.remove("clicked");
  
  this.classList.add("clicked");
  
  lastBtn = this;
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise solution. On click, it first removes `.clicked` from the button collection. Then it adds the class to the clicked button (which is available as `event.target`, the event (object) that triggered the function is always passed to the event handler automatically).

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction(event) {
  Array.forEach.call(0, btn, function(btn) {
    btn.classList.remove("clicked");
  });
  event.target.classList.add("clicked");
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers are good, but they don't remove the `clicked` class if the user clicks the same button again. To do it try this example:

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    if (!this.classList.contains("clicked")) {
        let prev = document.querySelector('.clicked')
        if (prev) prev.classList.remove("clicked");
        this.classList.add("clicked");
    } else {
        this.classList.remove("clicked");
    }
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## This is the shortest version

*Without `for-loop` nor `forEach` function, just Javascript function `querySelector`*

```
function myFunction() {
  var current = document.querySelector('.clicked')
  if (current) current.classList.remove('clicked');      
  this.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  var current = document.querySelector('.clicked')
  if (current) current.classList.remove('clicked');      
  this.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
  <button class="btn-color-black btn">Yo!</button>
</div>
```